# Color string in terminal in zsh

Tags: zsh, colors

I'm trying to convert this string that I had in .bash_profile

PS1="[\e[37;1m][\u:\w]$ [\e[0m]"

to an equivalent string in .zprofile in zsh. I've read the guide in

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zsh#Colors

but I actually didn't manage to understand the new syntax to color my terminal and, in my case, show the full path where I am actually working. I understand it's a trivial questions but also looking at related post I didn't manage to fix my issue. Any hint would be more than welcome :)

Thanks

Daniele

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
autoload -U colors && colors
export PS1="%F{250}%K{000}[$USER:%~]\$%F{015}%K{000} "
```

For more see my response here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58563434/1355058